# Submitting a HTML form in Flask creates error with request.form

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hey I am new to Flask and am trying to make a basic quiz app,

```
@app.route('/answers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def answers():
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    total = correct + incorrect
    if request.method == 'POST':
        submitted_answer = request.form['answer']
        if submitted_answer == question_option1:
            correct += 1
            new_result = Question(correct=correct, total=total)
            db.session.add(new_result)
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            incorrect += 1
            new_result = Question(incorrect=incorrect, total=total)
            db.session.add(new_result)
            db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/answers')
    all_questions = Question.query.order_by().all()
    return render_template('answers.html', questions=all_questions, correct=correct, incorrect=incorrect, total=total)
```

while the html code looks like this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
   <p1>
    <list>
       {% for question in questions %}
        <h2>{{ question.text }}</h2>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="option1"> {{ question.option1 }} <br>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="option2"> {{ question.option2 }} <br>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="option3"> {{ question.option3 }} <br>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="option4"> {{ question.option4 }} <br>

        {%  endfor %}

    </list>
       <form action='/answers' method='POST'>
           <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Check Scores">


       </form>
   <p1>You got a score of {{ correct }}/{{ total }}</p1>
   </p1>

{% endblock %}
```

In a different part of my app I am able to get information from the HTML using the same method but in this case I keep getting the error

'werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'answer''

when I try to submit the checklist and can't work out why

I am new to programming so sorry if i'm missing something very basic but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer inputs need to be inside the form tag to be submitted - there is no 'answer' element in the form you are submitting